# Using conditionals to check if LinearSolve found a solution

Tags: programming, linear-algebra

Is there some way to check if LinearSolve found a solution using conditionals in Mathematica 9? I need to solve a large number of linear equations, but I am only interested in the cases where there actually is a solution.

If there is no solution for the equation $Ax=b$, the output of LinearSolve will be

```
LinearSolve[A,b],
```

but I do not know how to exploit this.

Edit: I found a solution which should work with Mathematica 10:

```
StringFreeQ[TextString[LinearSolve[A,b]],LinearSolve]
```

first converts

```
LinearSolve[A,b]
```

into a string and then checks whether LinearSolve is part of that string. However, TextString only works with Mathematica 10 to which I do not have access.

Comment: Would `DeleteCases` not suffice?

Comment: can you post an example where `LinearSolve[A,b]` returns `LinearSolve[A,b]` and nothing else?

Comment: @Nasser If you take `A={{0,0},{0,0}}` and `b={1,0}`, then Mathematica will display a message that `LinearSolve` did not find a solution, which I guess is not considered as output, and `LinearSolve[{{0,0},{0,0}},{1,0}]` as "official" output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinearSolve` will generate an error message when it fail. Hence you can catch those messages. Number of ways to do this. Here is an example.

```
mat = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
b = {1, 0};
status = True;
status = Check[LinearSolve[mat, b], False, LinearSolve::nosol]

(* False*)
```

So `status` can be checked for `False`. If it is not `False`, then it passed. So simply set `status=False` before the call, and after the call do something like `If[Not[status]],... etc...`

No need to using strings and all of that.

reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html

Comment: `Check` even returns the value of the expression it evaluated if it passed and it lets you choose an arbitrary expression to return in case it did not. Thus there is no need to introduce a dummy variable for checking if you plan on working with the result of the computation anyway. Neat, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

checking the `Head` is another way, useful in a construct like this:

```
 alist = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}};
 Quiet@Select[  
    {#, LinearSolve[#, {1, 0}] } & /@ alist , Head@#[[2]] == List &
```

> {{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {1, 0}}}